# How will a man w. modern understanding of Physics, Programming and Chemistry understand and use magic without breaking the laws that governs it?

Tags: magic, medieval

Ok so we are in a world of magic in medieval age. And i am world building, i just need to further understand the magic that i had made with limitation stated below so it can be assumed that this is world building as it will affect the world that i had made

Medieval magic focuses primarily in elemental effect(Fire, water, earth and wind) and ethereal/metaphysical effect(soul, assuming it does exist) mind alteration does exist but it is rare.

> We have our NEET protagonist who is a prodigy in both physics,
>   chemistry(Phd level on both) and programming could affect his
>   understanding of magic and how it can be applied?

for example Munroe effect for armor piercing attacks, Electrical acceleration to have a railgun/coilgun, continuous casting with the help of looping rune(program) and etc.

you can assume runecrafting is almost the same as programming and can be fueled by either mana(internal magic), prana(external magic or worlds magic)

Limitations of magic is stated in laws below

Law of magic - Every magician worth his salt knows this, this is the limitation of what magic can do.

1. Law of equivalent exchange - You can't create more than what you
   have given. (Can be bypassed by Philosophers Stone)
2. Law of Preservation - You can't create anything out of nothingness.
3. Law of Noise - The more magicians are in the vicinity the harder it is to cast magic and its tendency to fail increases as well.(Can be bypassed if one recieved the God of Silence's blessing or massive rituals)
4. Law of Provision - Perversion of natures creation otherwise sentient will be reverted back to its original state or at the very least whats left of it in consideration of the first law.
5. Law of world - The world will always reject perversion of its reality.
6. Law of Time - No one can go to the future or past, offender will face the wrath of the gods and the world.

Comment: How scientifically hard is your magic? Does it allow HarryPotter-like transfiguration (match to needle, pin cushion to hedgehog, animagus transformation), or does it need to obey the normal rules of physics (law of thermodynamics, no nuclear element transmutation)?

Comment: @subrunner Animagus, and transfiguration falls over the law of the world, it will continually be rejected until it cant sustain itself then be reverted back to its original state. It obeys normal law of physics but that would probably be stretching it a bit and yes nuclear transmutation is a go, since nuclear reactions occur in nature

Comment: Just to clarify -- they CAN transmute lead to gold (i.e. changing the neutron and proton amounts in a nucleus)? Or is magic limited to molecule-level manipulations?

Comment: nope! but if you have philosopers stone you can!

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the question in your post? It seems like you want us to tell you your character's take on your magic system.

Comment: @Frostfyre done

Comment: What does it mean nature *rejects* pervasion? What is the effect of rejection? Is it similar to World of Darkness' Paradox (e.g. causing backlash of some sort, harming the magician in the process)?

Comment: @DoomedMind any reality altering phenomenon will be rejected by the world like for example resurrection of the dead, will result into a soul devouring ghoul instead of fully resurrected individual as the body doesnt posses soul as it has already pass the border of life and death.

Comment: @micovillena Then what counts as reality-altering?

Comment: cause and effect reversal, resurrection, butterfly effect manipulation, fate alteration, illusion reality reversal, luck manipulation, concept alteration, manipulation and destruction and such.

Comment: @micovillena then again, my question still about the rejection still is valid. How is rejection altering the intended effect of the spell?

Comment: @DoomedMind i'm sorry if i wasn't able to answer it properly, it will at first have weaker effect regardless of how much mana/prana has been poured in for example it should affect thousands by calculation but it will only affect hundreds.  later on it wears off depending on how powerful the spell is and how much of an effect it is altering the reality of the world. the more powerful the alteration is the harsher is the feed back which can range from unable to cast magic anymore to identity destruction.

Comment: @micovillena it may be helpful to add your specific question to the very end of the post. Here, you can use a different phrasing than in the title, using the entire post's content as context, so that your exact question will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question.

If magic in this world follows orderly, predictable laws, than it could be studied scientifically just like chemistry and physics. A scientific mindset would be well-suited to studying such magic.

If there are no laws, if things work or don't work with no discernable pattern or reason, then a scientific mindset might be a liability in understanding it.

I've read fantasy stories where the magic is incoherent. Often when reading such stories I find myself wondering, "If Foobar is such a powerful wizard, why can't he solve the problem by just magically teleporting the magic ring to the place where it will be destroyed? Why can't he defeat the trolls by throwing magic energy bolts at them, like he did to defeat the orcs in the previous chapter?" Etc. (Of course the real reason why magic works in case A but not in case B is because the first would advance the plot while the second would end the story too quickly.)

But you're talking about a bunch of laws governing magic. I think if I was writing a fantasy story with magic, I'd have a bunch of laws like that -- not necessarily the same as yours, but that there would be some set of laws that magic operates under, in a predictable fashion. But maybe that's just because I have a scientific mindset. :-)

Comment: i see, so he would probably suceed learning magic and probably stand above others due to his understanding of law of physics and such while others have rarely any idea of how does it happen and why

Comment: Yes. Indeed maybe there's a plot line there by itself. People in this alternate world know about magic, but they just know that Uncle Albert was once spinning a nonsense rhyme when suddenly a rock turned into a giraffe, so know they know that this particular string of sounds turns rocks into giraffes. Another time Crazy Betty got her hands tangled in her knitting yarn and when she was trying to get it untangled it turned into gold. Now they know that this series of hand gestures magically turns yarn into gold. Etc. But they have no idea how to go about creating new spells, because they ...

Comment: .... don't know the rules behind it. They only know spells that someone stumbled on by accident. Then one day a person with a scientfic frame of mind studies the known spells and says, "Oh, I see, sentences that have a rhyming pattern of A, B, B, A and exactly 12 syllables per line result in matter being transmuted. And if each line begins with a vowel sound then ..." etc. And he builds a systematic theory of the laws that govern magic.